# Express 'I feel..' Esp for phrases: 'I Feel like puking' or 'I feel old'?

Tags: phrases

I find myself in situations where I wanna express 'I feel like.. Puking(verb), eating(verb) pizza, I feel old (adj), etc'

How are these best expressed in Japanese?

Comment: There are 気がする, みたい and ～たい, for example.

Comment: `やばい、吐きそうやわ。ピザ食べたすぎてたまらん。やばい、年とったわ。`

Answer (score 6):

Some of these have their own set phrases or multiple ways of saying it. For example, if you feel like throwing up, you can say 吐き気がする or 吐きそう.

Another pattern you might see is something like 尿意を 催{もよお}す, which is basically to have the urge to pee, or to feel like peeing.

If you want to say "I feel old" then you can use 気がする again, like もうおじさんになった気がする (there are plenty of ways you could say this but I think most would use 気がする).

These represent a sense of "feel like" where we're making a rather objective statement about how we feel in an uncontrollable sense, not as an expression of will, and in most situations you'll probably use 気がする in some construction.

In an expression of will, like "I feel like eating pizza" (with the implication that you might therefore choose to eat pizza soon, or at least that you would if you could) you can use たい. Therefore it's fine to say ピザ食べたい. If that's too direct for you then you can emphasize that it's just a fleeting feeling by saying something like 今なぜかピザ食べたい気分だ, or "for some reason I feel like eating pizza now," with the insertion of 気分 indicating what you're in the mood for.　[～たい気分 is a common way of expressing this](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84%E6%B0%97%E5%88%86).